# Get individual option id of bundled product

Tags: magento, bundle, product

I am working with a GIANT list of bundled items, but only want to display certain ones as options based on entered criteria from the user.  This was easy enough by simply setting up an     if statement along the lines of:

```
$returnedproducts = array(21,50,78,23); // THESE ARE PRODUCT IDS.
if ($_product->getTypeId() == 'bundle'){
    $selectionCollection = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
           $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($_product), $_product
        );
    foreach($selectionCollection as $option) { 
      if(array_search($option['product_id'], $returnedproducts) !== FALSE){ // ADDED THIS TO FILTER
                  echo '<li>' .  $option->option_id . '</li>';
      }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this just sucks up tons of resources due to the size of the list and a few other factors.  I'd like to find a way to find and display only specific option ids without having to sift through the entire list (possible add a `WHERE product_id = XXXX` to the query that gets the options ids).  I can't seem to find a solution for searching for individual bundle options, though.  Can anyone help me achieve this?

Comment: Please don't put information in the subject line that you can provide in the tags; the tag system here works very well, and doesn't need to be assisted. :-) Thanks.

Comment: Note that I've tried to use `$selectionCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $returnedproducts));` to filter the collection down further but it doesn't seem to be working. If I get the MySQL statement from it it works fine, but as soon as the collection is loaded it somehow removes the `addFieldToFilter()`...

Comment: Did you try `addAttributeToFilter()` instead of `addFieldToFilter()`?

Answer (score -1):

I'll probably catch some backlash for this, but I've found that when you are reaching the upper limits of huge collections in Magento, you can do one of two things..

You can...

1. Throw money at your hosting solution for more ram / processors / etc
2. Use direct sql reads

Using sql reads is not particularly dangerous since you aren't going to be attempting to put something back into a highly managed database using code that has not been tested thoroughly.  Your chances are pretty slim of breaking anything.  Yes, there are off chances where things *may* go wrong but you need to weigh the cost / benefits of using a trick like this which is great for your specific case.  It is still using Magento's sql interface, not a custom one.

Modify the following code to pull a list of entity_ids or whatever you want to look up and use THAT result to create a collection.

```
// Just in case ---$mysqli = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$mysqlr = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');

$sql = "select * from some_entity_table where some_column = 'somevars'";

$results = $mysqlr->fetchAll($sql);

echo "<PRE>";
foreach ($results as $res)
{
    var_dump($res);
}
```